# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error' what(): basic_string::_M_create

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, reverse, function-definition

The problem is to reverse words in a string ...

```
Eg. - This is Nice
Output -Nice is This
```

so here's the error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_create
```

Here's my actual code, don't know where it went wrong I just started c++, but I'm sure I'm trying to access an index that isn't defined. Pls correct me if I'm wrong

```
string reverseWords(string s) {
        vector<string> v;
        string x="";
        for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
        {
            if(isspace(s[i]))
            {
                v.push_back(x);
                x="";
                v.push_back(" ");
                
            }
            else
            {
                x=x+s[i];
            }
        }
        v.push_back(x);
        x="";
        for(int j=v.size();j>=0;j--) x=x+v[j];
        return x;
    }
```

Comment: In the first iteration of `for(int j=v.size();j>=0;j--) x=x+v[j];` what is the value of `j` and how many elements are there in the vector? Would you say that works out or not?

Comment: FYI -- *The problem is to reverse words in a string* -- A simple `std::stack` and `std::stringstream` is all that's needed to solve this problem.

Comment: What is the topic of the chapter in your C++ textbook that you're using to learn C++, where this practice problem is from? Obviously you're expected to use whatever subject the chapter discusses in order to do this coding task, it's necessary to know that in order to point you in the right direction.

Comment: As to what I suggested, a `std::stringstream` automatically figures out where the spaces are, so no need for you to write the code to do this.  That alone cuts out much of the faulty code you have.

Comment: The final loop is going out of bounds of the vector, which is *undefined behavior*. You would need to start the loop at `v.size()-1`, but be careful if the vector is empty. Iterating the vector using reverse iterators would be a better choice instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is inefficient.

Also you are not reversing the source string but building a new string in the reversed order.

The compound statement of the if statement

```
if(isspace(s[i]))
{
    v.push_back(x);
    x="";
    v.push_back(" ");
    
}
```

does not make great sense when the source string contains adjacent spaces because it appends empty strings to the vector.

Also if the last character of the string is space then this statement after the for loop

```
v.push_back(x);
```

again appends a redundant empty string to the vector.

This for loop

```
for(int j=v.size();j>=0;j--) x=x+v[j];
```

invokes undefined behavior when `j` is equal to `v.size()`.

If you are dealing with an object of the type `std::string` then you should use methods of the class and standard algorithms as for example the algorithm `std::reverse`.

Here is a demonstration program that shows how a string can be reversed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

std::string & reverseWords( std::string &s, const char *delim = " \t" )
{
    auto first = s.find_first_not_of( delim );

    if (first != std::string::npos)
    {
        auto last = s.find_last_not_of( delim ) + 1;
        
        std::reverse( std::next( std::begin( s ), first ), std::next( std::begin( s ), last ) );

        while ( first != last )
        {
            auto pos = s.find_first_of( delim, first );

            if (pos == std::string::npos) pos = last;

            std::reverse( std::next( std::begin( s ), first ),
                std::next( std::begin( s ), pos ) );

            first = pos;

            if ( first != last ) first = s.find_first_not_of( delim, first );
        }
    }

    return s;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s( "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" );

    std::cout << s << '\n';
    std::cout << reverseWords( s ) << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
dog lazy the over jumps fox brown quick The
```